# Check if column is null or blank in DAX

Tags: ssas, dax

```
EVALUATE
FILTER
(
SUMMARIZE (
NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN (
    'Target_Category',
    'Target_Form'
    ),
'Target'[Area],
'Target'[id],
'Target'[Target date],
'Target'[Target Time Range],
'Target_Category'[Origin],
'Target_Category'[Sectotion],
'Target'[Location],
'Target_Category'[Ethencity],
'Target_FormResponse'[Area Used],
'Target'[Description]
),
'Target'[id] = Value("111373268") 
)
ORDEr BY 'Target'[Target Key]
```

1. I have the sample DAX query above. Is there away i can  manipulate `'Target_FormResponse'[Area Used]` such that if it is blank or empty, i return "No" otherwise if its not blank or empty i return "Yes".

In SSRS, i can do something like `=IIF(Len(Fields!Form_Response.Value) > 0,"Yes","No")` but i want to achieve this at the DAX query level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are satisfied with adding an extra column that contains the "Yes" or "No" values, simple wrap the entire expression in a call to [`ADDCOLUMNS`](https://dax.guide/addcolumns):

```
EVALUATE
ADDCOLUMNS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE (
            NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN ( 'Target_Category', 'Target_Form' ),
            'Target'[Area],
            'Target'[id],
            'Target'[Target date],
            'Target'[Target Time Range],
            'Target_Category'[Origin],
            'Target_Category'[Sectotion],
            'Target'[Location],
            'Target_Category'[Ethencity],
            'Target_FormResponse'[Area Used],
            'Target'[Description]
        ),
        'Target'[id] = VALUE ( "111373268" )
    ),
    "Area Used Yes/No", IF ( 'Target_FormResponse'[Area Used] > 0, "Yes", "No" )
)
ORDER BY 'Target'[Target Key]
```

If you want to get rid of the original column in the output, you'd have to use [`SELECTCOLUMNS`](https://dax.guide/selectcolumns) instead, but unfortunately, you'd then have to specify the names of each of the columns you want to keep, so the code ends up a lot longer.